Deformation when follow path

I began to use Blender a few weeks ago.
I have a problem when I ask my camera to follow a path. When I change the rotation values on my Z-axis, I see a second yellow square on my camera, and its view is deformed.
I can solve it by adjusting the influence of my path to zero, but the camera no longer follows the path.
Thanks for your help.

hello could you please share the curve + camera ?

How to do that?

You can share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

I put a screen shot if you want to see the deformation with the camera view and this is not the rotation on the y axis but on the z axis

You need to apply all transforms (Ctrl + A with the path selected in Object Mode) to the path link with the camera in the constraints.
